# How to check whether you are getting data from data base?

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation

I have an asp.net web page. In that I have a gridview. I'm getting data to grid view like this.

```
public void fillGridWithIdlingTitles()
{
    GVView.DataSource = new VWIDLTitlesOP().getIdlingTitlesList();
    GVView.DataBind();
}
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        fillGridWithIdlingTitles();
    }
}
```

And this is my business layer method.

```
 public DataTable getIdlingTitlesList()
{
    string myQ = "EXEC GetTitlesWOLoansForLast365Days";
    return new DataAccessLayer().executeTable(myQ);
}
```

I want to validate my data grid view. If my data base doesn't have matching data to the query, I just DON"T want to display an empty page. I want to show, Sorry there's no matching records in another controller like a label.

How can I check if I'm getting data from the data base in an if condition. Or how can I check whether the data grid view is not having data?

Any help would be great.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the resulting `DataTable` for rows:

```
var dataTable = new VWIDLTitlesOP().getIdlingTitlesList();
GVView.DataSource = dataTable;

if (dataTable.Rows.Count == 0)
{
   ...
}
```

(and please use `PascalCase` instead of `camelCase` for methods).

Comment: Thanks for your kindness in answering. Thanks for the advice. I'll follow PascalCase.

Answer (score 0):

You have a few options:

1. Get a count of rows through your SQL query and check that value ( `SELECT COUNT(*) nrOfRows ...` )
2. Count the number of rows the DataTable contains which you are returning at `getAllOverDueLoans();`

I'd pref the 2nd one for simplicity.

Now simply check if the count is greater than zero or else display some message

```
if(dt.Rows.Count > 0)
{

}
else
{

}
```

Comment: I like this method, but then I will have to change my stored procedure right? Anyway thanks for your kindness in helping.